# Property for all buttons in view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, view, properties

I have an application for the iPad and I have a lot of buttons. After clicking on a place, I need to set all buttons property that will be the same for all, I wonder how to do it? For example, all buttons in the view will have a black layer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Storyboard, assign all your buttons to a Reference Outlet Collection.

[image]

this will give you an NSArray with all the buttons you've assigned to it, then you can use 
for..in loop to affect change to each button.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the setup of your app, the most generic answer would be:

1. Add all buttons you will want to change to an array.
2. When you click on "the place" as described in your question, iterate through that array.
3. Make the change to each of the buttons.

I can't give you any specific code, but it could look something like:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtons = [NSMutableArray array];
//add all your buttons to the array
//user clicks "the place" run code:
for (UIButton *oneOfTheButtons in arrayOfButtons) {
    oneOfTheButtons.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: And obviously if this were all you were doing then you'd more likely use a set than an array, but you get the picture.